# Starting HBASE, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to start HBASE with start-hbase.sh, however, I get the error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder.`

I have tried to add various `.jar`'s to various folders (as suggested in other threads) but nothing works. I am using Hadoop 3.11 and HBase 2.10 Here is the (end of the) error log.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster. 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2983)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/SamplerBuilder
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils.getRootDir(CommonFSUtils.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils.isValidWALRootDir(CommonFSUtils.java:407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils.getWALRootDir(CommonFSUtils.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeFileSystem(HRegionServer.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:484)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2965)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: please share us the HBase version your are trying with and also the snippet of htrace-core jar in HBASE_HOME & HADOOP_HOME to check the version. Thanks!

Comment: Yes ofc, using Hadoop 3.11 and HBase 2.10

Answer (score 6):

HBase 2.1.0 release uses HTrace, that is an incubating Apache Foundation project.

There is a folder for 3rd-party libraries in HBase `lib` folder, `client-facing-thirdparty`. You need to copy `htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar` from there to the HBase lib directory. [(see reference)](http://www.techguru.my/database/hbase/install-hbase-2-x-with-hadoop-3-x/)

There is also another solution at [Cloudera Community](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/ClassNotFoundException-org-apache-htrace-Trace-exception-in/m-p/29253) that changes a configuration instead of adding the library manually.

Comment: If I `cd` to `/usr/local/hbase/lib/client-facing-thirdparty` and do `dir`, I only get a single `htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar`, even though I have the same problem.

Comment: @Mooncrater did you copy this file to HBase lib folder?

Comment: @Mooncrater did you copy the `htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar` file **from** `$HBASE_HOME/lib/client-facing-thirdparty` **to** `$HBASE_HOME/lib` folder?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to have been a compatibility issue between Hbase and Hadoop, I reverted to using Hadoop 2.9.1 and Hbase 1.2.6 together with JDK 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

HBase 2.1.4 has no `htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar` in `client-facing-thirdparty`

You need copy from 2.1.3 or download from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.htrace/htrace-core