# NoClassDefFoundError while running HBase, no error in zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, hbase, config

I've created a standalone hadoop cluster using [this](http://hadoop.praveendeshmane.co.in/hadoop/hadoop-2-6-4-pseudo-distributed-mode-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04.jsp) tutorial. Then I installed `HBase` over `hadoop` by following [this](http://hbase.praveendeshmane.co.in/hbase/hbase-1-2-3-pseudo-distributed-mode-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04.jsp) tutorial.

I ran Hadoop by

```
cd /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/
./start-all.sh
```

And HBase by

```
cd /usr/local/hbase/bin
./start-hbase.sh
```

Then when I do `jps`, I get:

```
3761 Jps
835 NameNode
966 DataNode
3480 HMaster
3608 HRegionServer
1465 ResourceManager
1610 NodeManager
3418 HQuorumPeer
1150 SecondaryNameNode
```

But after some time it shows:

```
1779 SecondaryNameNode
1557 DataNode
2870 HQuorumPeer
2200 NodeManager
2061 ResourceManager
3246 Jps
1423 NameNode
```

So that's a pretty large indicator that something is wrong. Now, I checked the zookeeper logs in `/usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-hduser-zookeeper-stal.log` and it showed:

```
2019-04-29 07:54:45,677 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2019-04-29 07:54:45,677 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2019-04-29 07:54:45,677 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:os.name=Linux
2019-04-29 07:54:45,678 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2019-04-29 07:54:45,678 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:os.version=4.15.0-47-generic
2019-04-29 07:54:45,678 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:user.name=hduser
2019-04-29 07:54:45,678 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:user.home=/home/hduser
2019-04-29 07:54:45,678 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:user.dir=/home/hduser
2019-04-29 07:54:45,782 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: tickTime set to 3000
2019-04-29 07:54:45,782 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: minSessionTimeout set to -1
2019-04-29 07:54:45,782 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: maxSessionTimeout set to 90000
2019-04-29 07:54:46,780 INFO  [main] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
```

which doesn't seem like any error whatsoever.

So, I checked HBase's errors in `/usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-hduser-master-stal.log` and I got:

```
2019-04-29 07:55:11,513 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:3111)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/SamplerBuilder
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2683)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils.getRootDir(CommonFSUtils.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils.isValidWALRootDir(CommonFSUtils.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils.getWALRootDir(CommonFSUtils.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeFileSystem(HRegionServer.java:704)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:613)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:489)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3093)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 25 more
```

There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106952/starting-hbase-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-htrace-samplerbuild/53959014?noredirect=1#comment98446413_53959014), which was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53959014/5345646) by:

> HBase 2.1.0 release uses HTrace, that is an incubating Apache
>   Foundation project.
>
> There is a folder for 3rd-party libraries in HBase lib folder,
>   client-facing-thirdparty. You need to copy
>   htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar from there to the HBase lib
>   directory. ([see reference](http://www.techguru.my/database/hbase/install-hbase-2-x-with-hadoop-3-x/))
>
> There is also another solution at [Cloudera Community](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/ClassNotFoundException-org-apache-htrace-Trace-exception-in/m-p/29253) that changes a
>   configuration instead of adding the library manually.

The first solution includes:

> 1. The HMaster refuse to start due to the error below:
>
> Java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder
>
> This is because in hbase 2.0, we have 2 different version of
>   `htrace-core.x.x.x.incubating.jar`
>
> ```
> cd /usr/local/hbase/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/:
> htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar
> htrace-core-4.2.0-incubating.jar
> ```
>
> Currently, only version 3.1.0 has the required class `SamplerBuilder`.
>   We need to remove version 4.2.0:
>
> `mv htrace-core-4.2.0-incubating.jar htrace-core-4.2.0-incubating.jar.bak`
>   But, when I did `cd` to the `/usr/local/hbase/lib/client-facing-thirdparty` and do `ls -a` I get:

```
.   audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar  findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar   log4j-1.2.17.jar      slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
..  commons-logging-1.2.jar         htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar  slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
```

As one can see, there is only one `htrace` file, not two. So, I downloaded `htrace-3.1.0`, from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.htrace/htrace-core/3.1.0-incubating), and copied it into `/usr/local/hbase/lib/client-facing-thirdparty`, and renamed `htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar` to `htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar.bak`. Then I restarted `hadoop` and `HBase`. Still no change. `jps` didn't show `HMaster` and `HRegionServer` now.

---

`HBase` configuration files:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
<value>/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>localhost</value>
</property>

<property> 
<name>hbase.master</name> 
<value>localhost:60010</value> 
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/hbase/tmp</value>
        <description>Temporary directory on the local filesystem.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

And `hbase-env.sh` looks like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=/usr/local/hbase/conf/regionservers
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
export HBASE_PID_DIR=/var/hbase/pids
export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

---

So, what should I do now? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Generally, I suggest avoiding downloading things directly from the Apache sites (or following tutorials written over 2-3 years ago) and configuring things yourself. Stick to installing Cloudera or Hortonworks distributions where things are actually tested to make sure they work together. Stability is better than bleeding edge features.